# Laravel- Termplate blade not loading inner views

Tags: php, view, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have divided my template like there is a main template and inside that template, there is a `nav` are and then `content` area but it is loading only content
my controller function is

```
public function index() {

        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }
```

**app.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-XdYbMnZ/QjLh6iI4ogqCTaIjrFk87ip+ekIjefZch0Y+PvJ8CDYtEs1ipDmPorQ+" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        {{-- <link href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> --}}

        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Lato';
            }

            .fa-btn {
                margin-right: 6px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body id="app-layout">
        @yield('nav')

        @yield('content')

        <!-- JavaScripts -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-I6F5OKECLVtK/BL+8iSLDEHowSAfUo76ZL9+kGAgTRdiByINKJaqTPH/QVNS1VDb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        {{-- <script src="{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}"></script> --}}
</body>
</html>
```

**dashboard.blade.php**

```
@extends('admin.layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Welcome</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    Your Application's Landing Page.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**nav.blade.php**

```
@extends('admin.layouts.app')
@section('nav')
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <!-- Branding Image -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                Laravel
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
            <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a></li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <!-- Authentication Links -->
                @if(Auth::guard('admin')->user())
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                        {{ Auth::guard('admin')->user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/admin/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                @endif
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true, you need to change your code a bit.

If I use the following structure:

```
- views
  - layouts
    - app.blade.php
    - nav.blade.php
- dashboard.blade.php
```

Here is your `app.blade.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-XdYbMnZ/QjLh6iI4ogqCTaIjrFk87ip+ekIjefZch0Y+PvJ8CDYtEs1ipDmPorQ+" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        {{-- <link href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> --}}

        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Lato';
            }

            .fa-btn {
                margin-right: 6px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body id="app-layout">
        @include('layouts.nav')

        @yield('content')

        <!-- JavaScripts -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-I6F5OKECLVtK/BL+8iSLDEHowSAfUo76ZL9+kGAgTRdiByINKJaqTPH/QVNS1VDb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        {{-- <script src="{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}"></script> --}}
</body>
</html>
```

This will `include` the navbar inside your layout.

You `dashboard.blade.php` will look like:

```
@extends('admin.layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Welcome</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    Your Application's Landing Page.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Hope this works!

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#extending-a-layout

Comment: This throws `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 56494 bytes) in /var/www/html/biovideo_web/storage/framework/views/af33946962d0bc0f5ef4088c2cf48aee8a4abeec.php on line 24` error